# After baking my water simulation the play back of the water is tiny colored dots

Tags: fluid-simulation

After baking my water simulation. The playback of the water is coloured dots, tiny ones.

What is the setting to change this? I have watched youtube tutorials and I followed them step-by-step but it still doing the simulation wrong and it playing it with tiny coloured dots. Please can someone help?

Comment: I think you have just baked the physics for the simulation and not the mesh

Comment: I guess @MexicanLucky is right, you have either not baked a mesh or you are in wireframe view so you can see through the mesh. Anyway, these colored dots are the fluid particles, so basically your simulation worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdUWqkqcxzw

You're just not in the right viewport shading, try changing it to render preview in the top right of your viewport.